# Oracle In-Clause Parameter Padding

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Suppose an in-clause can accept a varying number of bind parameters.  In this case, databases can have a hard time caching the query.  Basically, each time a different number of bind parameters is passed, the query needs to be hard parsed.  Enter "parameter padding".  Parameter padding will take an in-clause and increase the number of binds to the closest 2^x number of binds.

**Examples:**

- `select count(*) from user where id in (1, 2, 3)` becomes `select count(*) from user where id in (1, 2, 3, 3)`
- `select count(*) from user where id in (1, 2, 3, 4)` remains `select count(*) from user where id in (1, 2, 3, 4)`

And now these two queries can share the same cached plan.

**Question:** Is there a logical reason for 2^x binds?  Why not 3^x or 5^x so that even fewer hard parses are required?  This would be especially helpful in queries that contain multiple in-clauses with varying binds.

The specific database in question is Oracle 12c.  Using stats for a query that has an in-clause of `in (1, 2, 3, 3)` shows that the duplicate values do not appear in the execution plan.  Furthermore, using stats for a query requiring 30 binds runs just as efficiently when using an in-clause of the exact 30 values needed OR using an in-clause with 100 values where the last value appears 70 more times.

Comment: There may not be any reason for 2^x beyond computers work in binary so using base 2 is most natural.

Comment: It seems like this is a question about a specific JOOQ/Hibernate 'in-list padding' feature. If so can you confirm and update the tags accordingly to make that clear for readers? This seems like nothing more than a band-aid to rectify performance issues caused by Hibernate generating queries transforming 3GL arrays to in-lists of variable lengths. In general in Oracle (e.g. PL/SQL) we would typically not take this approach to query using large lists of either bind variables or literals (since it would imply dynamic SQL) instead we would pass collection types or use temporary tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tradeoff:

If you choose, say, 5^x, then for 7 parameters your IN-list will have 25 members, instead of just 8. The query will then take longer to run - the fact that the tail values are all equal won't help.

Note that your example of an explain plan for the IN-list of (1,2,3,3) is irrelevant. That has hard-coded values, not bind variables. The relevant example is (:bind1, :bind2, :bind3, :bind4); when the query is parsed, the optimizer can't assume that :bind3 will always equal :bind4 (for the obvious reason that that's not even true in general).

2^x is usually a good tradeoff between "how many hard parses to allow" and "how fast the queries will be". Otherwise you could just use a single query, with 1000 parameters (the max allowed) - why even have more than ONE such query?

Comment: I'm not convinced that the query will take longer to run.  At least from Oracle's execution stats a query with in (?,?,?,?) vs a query with where there are 150 ? in the in clause had nearly identical stats.  Like 3.88 seconds vs 3.89 seconds.

However, it makes sense, as you stated, that there's some overhead of applying the bind list to the placeholders which is not being tracked in the execution stats.

Comment: @user1333371 - that may be, but then all you need is a single query, with 1000 binds in the IN list. I mentioned that  at the end of my answer.